# Client area getting cropped in WinForms Usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, user-controls

I am working on a Windows Forms `UserControl` which displays a dynamic user interface. The GUI is defined in an XML file which this `UserControl` reads from, and then adds .NET Windows Forms controls to it. It is working properly, but sometimes the ends of the TextBox controls are being cropped, as shown in the images below:

This is the way the TCP tab should appear

[image]

[image]

But as shown in the second image, the TextBox controls get cropped for some reason when I use nested TabControls. The nesting of the tab controls is not the reason for them getting cropped. It happens with some other formats also. Sometimes if you recreate the control it appears perfectly. I am using `FlowLayoutPanel` for placing child controls on tab pages. All controls are created and added dynamically to UserControl.

Any clues why this maybe happening?

Comment: Hello @Ram. Please show us the part of the XML file that relates to the affected controls.

Comment: The UserControl.Size property is simply too small.  Set the form's BackColor to something else to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please post the code that relates to this artifact?

A quick guess: since you add all controls dynamically, did you set the `Size` of your dynamically added `FlowLayoutPanel` properly or set it to `AutoSize`? If not, the controls that stand on location outside the `FlowLayoutPanel` rectangle will be cropped.

Comment: That was the problem, the flowlayoutpanel was not getting properly resized.